How is Reading Without Understanding of Its Language Processed in the Brain
As an author of a comprehensive book that discusses many of the processes involved in teaching and learning Hebrew reading, I am currently making a major revision and would like to find out more information on this topic.
Specifically, ​I would like to research the stages of reading acquisition that are specific to reading a phonetic language such as Hebrew, as it doesn't require knowledge of the language itself​.
Many Jewish students across the world (besides Israel), do not require the student to know the meaning of the word that they are reading since Hebrew is phonetic, i.e., it is read always the way it looks.​
Additionally, I would like to know how this ​is related to cognitive, associative, and autonomous aspects of skill building.

Welcome to psych.SE. This is a Q&A site. What is your specific question?

Thank you Arnon for encouraging me to sharpen my question. I hope this works now.
